# Nokogiri strategy for identifying largest text on a page?

Tags: ruby, xpath, html-parsing, nokogiri, text-parsing

I'm doing a comparison of a bunch of landing pages in the wild.  I'm trying to pull out the main header and the call to action, but of course the HTML formatting of the pages varies wildly.

I started looking for H1, H2, etc. assuming that the header tags correspond to primacy, but this is often not the case. Rendered font-size* might be a better indicator, however this seems messy and wouldn't handle cases where images with alt tags are used.

**What's a good strategy to identify the main heading of 100 wild landing pages using Nokogiri?**

*Also- is there a clever selector for rendered font-size?

Comment: If they don't have headers in h1/2 god bless their google position ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it unless you have an AI running that can determine the most semantically important section of a document.

You can't count on the tags, such as headers or meta-tags, because those can be missing entirely.

You can't count on location in the source because CSS can move things anywhere.

And, even if you think you've got it nailed by looking at the CSS, the JavaScript can rip that reality from you because it can override everything, relying on the fact it takes a human's eyes and brain to make sense of the final rendered page.

So, basically, you're going to be mostly shooting in the dark unless you have code that can understand the content of the page and determine how often a word occurs, along with its synonyms and their root words, and then determine their placement on the page *after* CSS and JavaScript have been run.

It's really a tough task that a lot of big companies are spending a lot of money on.

Comment: Agreed. The more time I've spent on this and the larger the set of pages I add to my dataset the more edge cases I discover.  I'm leaning towards a relatively stupid set of heuristics to pull an 80/20 solution, which would then be suggested side by side with a screen grab of the page for human confirmation / clean-up.

Comment: That's the path I went down. When I was writing code to do keyword analysis, I had the benefit of working with a Linguistics expert with a doctorate in the field, and it was really interesting how we'd come to the same conclusions via separate paths of the difficulty of cracking this particular nut. It's a great challenge though.